# Unrecognized selector NSInvalidArgumentException: for IBAction?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I am facing a strange problem in iOS iPad app. My application is crashing when I map a `UIButton` to an `IBAction` with touch up inside event. The error I get in the console is like
`Unrecognized selector NSInvalidArgumentException`.

By the way all the view controllers in my project have the same problem. The view controllers are mapped to a tab bar controller.

I have created this project by dragging and dropping all the files from another project. The dragged files are placed properly in the current project, no problem with that. Will this cause problem?

I was not able to figure out what went wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Copied the storyboards over or just the code?

Comment: Does that button has any other connection in outlet other than your method?

Comment: Does the method in implementation is same as declared method in header file?

Comment: Are you wiring touch up inside event by code or from Nib ?

Comment: Today I created a new project in ios, wired a UIButton to action called "go", having only nslog(@"go"); But got the same error. I tried to point out the error, after 15 minutes I recreated new project, same way same code...it worked!!! Is it time to switch to AppCode or after 5yrs in XCode we are still under learning and knowing our XCode?

Comment: Yes Rajneesh, I have given my own solution to this post. Please verify that. Thanks for your concern. ! Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I have resolved the problem.

**Actual Problem:**

1. My project is with ARC.
2. Actually i am navigating to a new view from one view to other by adding it as subview by clicking a button with `IBAction` as below,

   ```
   -(IBAction)signInAndGoToFrameworkView :(id)sender{  

   MyViewController myViewController  = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController " bundle:nil];
   [self.view addSubview:myViewController.view];

   }
   ```

3 . As the project is with ARC, the object myViewController is released since this is a local variable. So when i press back button to do

```
   [self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

the app was getting crashed.

**Solution:**

So when i just declared `MyViewController myViewController` in .h file and also given `@property` and `@synthesize`. Then changed the `IBAction` with,

```
   -(IBAction)signInAndGoToFrameworkView :(id)sender{  

    myViewController  = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController " bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:myViewController.view];

    }
```

Now the problem solved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on your button in xib and check that you have only one connection for your button, if you have more then one then please delete unwanted connection .

[image]

Comment: I have only one connection. No problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the class of your custom `UIViewController` subclass in interface builder?

[image]

Comment: Yes thats already set like you said. For instance its like MyViewController.

Answer (score 1):

If problem stil survives after applying the solution by **Gabriele Petronella** and **Rajneesh071** then there is a chance one small mistake :

If you are using :

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then `buttonTouched` method must be `(IBAction)`.

If `buttonTouched` method is of type `(void)` then just remove that **`:`** from your method call.

I know it's a simple thing, but it may result in crash.

Comment: I thought only IBAction typed methods show up in IB. If it was a void, I don't it would show up in the list of methods to choose from for his Action in IB.

Comment: @Jazzmine : ya that's i know. That's why i asked Kanaga if he has written the code manually or wired up the Outlets.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure you have the unrecognized method(s) referenced by the UIButton:

1) is the method signature listed in your .h consistent with the method signature listed in your .m file?
 2) are any expected arguments passed when you call them method?
 3) is the method consistently listed as a class (+) or instance (-) method in your .h and .m files?

I know you said you copied the files over but did you test to make sure the app you copied from also works? Does the other app have the method hooked up to a button? Did you change ANYTHING after you copied it over?

Cheers